# How do I restore my PATH in ~/.bashrc when basic commands don't work?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

While installing a program on Ubuntu, I messed up paths in my ~/.bashrc. Now I cannot use Linux commands like ls, vim, etc. Therefore I cannot edit the ~/.bashrc file (it's a cluster). How can I fix my shell startup files?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: You can also check [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. PATH and environment settings seem perfectly on-topic, as Bash programming is a legitimate topic here. There is definitely some overlap with SuperUser, but I don't think this should be a close magnet.

Comment: `while read -r x; do echo "$x"; done < /etc/skel/.bashrc > ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Specify a Fully-Qualified Path to Your Editor

Specifying an absolute path to your editor (e.g. vim, nano, or emacs) will generally enable you to fix up your shell startup files. For example, to edit and re-source your Bash resource file:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bashrc &&
    . ~/.bashrc
```

### Start a Clean Environment

If you just want to start a new shell without inheriting from your current environment or sourcing your current .profile or .bashrc file, you can do that. For example:

```
/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --noprofile --norc
```

You should then be able to rely on sane system defaults to edit your *PATH* or other settings before sourcing your shell's startup files manually or just execing a new shell with:

```
command exec /bin/bash
```

### Override PATH in the Current Shell

You might also try overriding the PATH in your current shell with system defaults using the standard *getconf* utility. For example:

```
export PATH=$(command getconf PATH)
```

You can also set your PATH manually to a minimal sane default like:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

so you can continue to work on your issue.

### Clusters and Distributed Systems

This aspect is likely outside the scope of a site about programming, especially since we don't have enough information about your systems. In general, if you messed up system-wide or clustered environment settings, you may need to look at values in /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d, /etc/skel, NFS shares, or other locations where your account or application PATH is being set.

If the problem is local to an account, then the tips I provided above will help. You might also consider logging into another account that doesn't exhibit the same problems.

Knowing where to fix a multi-system configuration issue, or knowing what your system- or user-specific PATH settings should be, is outside the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow question. Short of that, though, any of the solutions above should work.

Answer (score 4):

If your $PATH is lost, no problem, you can find your editor in any of the usual places like `/usr/bin/`.

So you can start your edit with:

```
/usr/bin/vim .bashrc
```

You can much easier create simply a new one if you create a new user with your distribution and simply copy the .bashrc file from there to your own home directory. Each distribution provides a simple gui tool to add a new user to the system. So that should work without having a valid .bashrc.

What makes me wonder: All my PATH settings are not in .bashrc directly but in a system wide one. On fedora it is something like:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

For ubuntu it will be different. But doesn't matter, because the creation of a new user will also help in this case ;)